# Integrate legacy On-Prem .Net application to GCP using Tibco and GCP Pub/Sub

Tags: java, .net, .net-core, google-cloud-pubsub, tibco-ems

We are in the process of integrating .Net applications which are deployed on VM's on premises data centers with pub/sub resource topic in Google cloud platform on the cloud. I have a scenario which I am currently not able to decide and would need help and a right direction. Below is the brief detail of the use case. Please have a look and provide your thoughts.

Currently there is a .Net application which is deployed on a Windows VM on legacy on-prem client data centers. What it does is that it publishes XML messages to a Tibco EMS topic on a EMS server deployed in same data centers on-prem. Few Java applications which are deployed on different VM's subscribe to this Tibco topic and pull messages and process them. This is the legacy flow.

As a part of modernization GCP is coming into the mix. Now the scenario is that XML messages that On-Prem .Net application publishes to the Tibco topic should also get pushed to pub/sub resource topic on GCP cloud. A Java microservice which has been deployed on GCP infra would subscribe to this topic and consume these messages from it.

Now the problem I am facing is that how to go about this integration between On-Prem and Cloud applications. I thought about a couple of options.

1. Copy the messages directly from legacy Tibco topic to which .Net app publishes messages to Pub/sub topic in GCP. I am not a Tibco expert and not sure If this is supported. I found the below link but not sure if this suits my use-case. Also client wants to move away from Tibco and not sure if the legacy Tibco EMS on data centers support the below Tibco connector feature.
   https://www.tibco.com/connected/google-cloud-pub/sub
2. Make changes to the .Net code base so that point in code where it publishes message to Tibco topic we can add additional code to also publish it directly to Pub/Sub topic in GCP. Not sure if this is ok as .Net application is on legacy on-prem VM and the Pub/Sub is in the Cloud. Here also I not familiar with .Net but found out that there are .Net Google client library which can be added in .Net code to achieve this flow. Also is Google Pub/Sub the right integration tool to be used or something else has to be used to connect these two systems to-gather.

This is by far i could proceed. Could you guys let me know are the above 2 approaches right or there is an issue and which one is the right approach. Also if there is any other solution apart from above it would really help me to move forward. Hoping for a positive reply and help from you all.

Thanks, Vikeng21

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st scenario the mentioned connector is in fact a TIBCO BusinessWorks plugin. So the approach would be to build a kind of GCP Cloud Messaging / TIBCO EMS gateway using TIBCO BusinessWorks. It would be then possible to run this solution on premise or in the Cloud (using TIBCO TCI offering).
The advantage of this approach is that it would be transparent for your applications and local .Net applications and Cloud applications would receive exact same messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think EmmanuelM's answer covers the first scenario, it would probably be the easiest and most transparent approach.

In regards of scenario #2. I think this is a valid approach as well, although it requires to modify your application code to publish messages to Pub/Sub alongside Tibco, I'm no Tibco expert either; but when it comes to Pub/Sub, as you've mentioned, Pub/Sub offers a [.NET client library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/) which you can you use in your application to easily publish and consume Pub/Sub messages. I see that you've mentioned:

> Not sure if this is ok as .Net application is on legacy on-prem VM and the Pub/Sub is in the Cloud

It is completely ok; Cloud Pub/Sub service is used through [its API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/service_apis_overview), and you can consume the API regardless of whether you do it on-prem or cloud.

The thing about this approach is that I'm not sure how consistency could be kept between Tibco and Pub/Sub, I'm assuming that this is why the first approach would be easier and transparent as this is probably what the integration plugin is in charge of. Without that, some custom application logic would probably be required to guarantee that messages are being successfully published both to Tibco and Pub/Sub.

Having said that, I would really recommend that you get in [contact with Google Cloud Sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact/?pre_product=googleMapsPlatform&hl=ar-IL) to describe in detail your use case, business requirements and get personalized assistance for your migration plan.